# Value is exists in custom metadata list

Tags: apex, custom-metadata

I have a list of Custom metadata (Part_one_metadata__mdt) which contains a list of lables (Sunday, Monday, Saturday).

Then I am creating a string (public String Medicine) and passing a value. Now I want to check if value passed in String contains one of the labels.

public String Medicine;

Shall I loop it?

Comment: Hi @thomas-mckiny, welcome to stackexchange. For the community to help your problem, you should share the code you have tried till now. This makes it easier for the others to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store your  list of labels from `Part_one_metadata__mdt` in a `List<String>` and use the [contains()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_list.htm) method.

```
List<String> myCustomMetadataLabels = 'get labels from Part_one_metadata__mdt';
Public String medicine = 'Sunday';
Boolean result = myCustomMetadataLabels.contains(medicine);
System.assertEquals(true, result);
```

Comment: I think you meant a Set, not a List